# Avoid repetitive API calling in form rebuild while submitting

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I am calling external API in form build function. While submitting form gets rebuild and call external API again.

How can I avoid repetitive API calls in the form's build function? I used `form_state->set()` but it's doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You should paste your code to check how you are using set(). The idea is correct: save API response to form, and don't request it again in build function if info is already in form.

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether the form is currently rebuilding using the [`FormStateInterface::isRebuilding`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AisRebuilding/8.6.x) method:

```
if (!$form_state->isRebuilding()) {
  // Contact the API
}
```

Comment: Not working in my case. Tried even in simple form.

Comment: It always works fine for me, you'll probably need to be more specific about what "not working" means for you

Comment: @Clive, this works when you rebuild the form after submitting, but not when the form gets rebuilt while submitting. In this case you could check for user input `if (empty($form_state->getUserInput())) {}`

Comment: @4k4 Those sound like the same thing, what's the difference? Is it just calling it in `buildForm` rather than `submitForm`?

Comment: @Clive, a form can be built three times during one cycle, the initial form build, then before the submit handlers are called and finally after the form is submitted and a rebuild is requested. Only the last includes submitted form values and indicates $form_state->isRebuilding() correctly.

Comment: @4k4 Good to know, thanks :) Would you mind writing that up in an answer so I can delete this one?

Comment: @4k4 I need to store API values so that I can access those values in a rebuild which have some form conditions based on API response.

Comment: Need solution same like this answer which was for d7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874087/can-i-stop-drupal-re-creating-a-form-when-its-submitted

Comment: @Rahul, there is no clear solution for D7 and this is is getting in D8 even more difficult because of caching. I would consider to refactor the API calls into a service with its own caching.